# Using CSS and DIVs how do you stack two small content boxes next to one big content box

Tags: css, css-float

How to I use CSS to arrange my three div tags to look like this?

Two small content boxes stacked on each other with a small space between (to the left) of a large content box (to the right)

Thanks

Comment: I know they say don't, but for complicated (and simple) layouts, tables make it so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

use a div to contain your two small on the left and make this div `float:left;`. You might also want to give this div a fixed width. Then you can put your big div on the right using `margin-right:x;` x being an amount that you will have to ajust depending on the situation.

Comment: i think putting margin-right:Xpx; will not do it, float right could do it and then yes margin right

Comment: well working with div as always been a mater of trying stuff and see what works so I gave him the idea behind how you do it

Answer (score 0):

I usually wrap the left divs in another div to keep everything tidy. You could use this CSS:

```
#left{
    float:left;
    width: 45%;
}
#left1{
    background-color:#ff0;    
    height: 100px;
}
#left2{
    background-color:#f0f;    
    height: 100px;  
}
#right{
    background-color:#0ff;    
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    float:right;
 }
```

And this HTML:

```
​<div id="left">
    <div id="left1">stuff</div>
    <div id="left2">more stuff</div>
</div>
<div id="right">even more stuff</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/XnBe9/

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help... the advice worked perfectly, just what I needed. - Thanks